# Compare two date fields with two date parameters

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, linq

I have two columns in the database, project_start and project_end, and I'm in passing two fields (both optional) via a report (coded in ASP).

The pseudo code below is what I currently have:

(project_start <= search_start AND project_end <= search_start)

AND

(project_start <= search_end AND project_end >= search_end)

However what the above doesn't pick up are projects which start before the start date, but end after the start date, projects which start after the start date but end after the end date, and also projects which start before the start date and end after the end date :S

Below is my code:

```
if (Request.QueryString["DateFrom"] != null && Request.QueryString["DateFrom"] != "")
        {
            DateTime dateFromFilter;

            dateFromFilter = DateTime.Parse(Request.QueryString["DateFrom"]);

            Q = from qua in qTable
                    where qua.Start_Date.Date <= dateFromFilter.Date
                    && qua.End_Date.Date >= dateFromFilter.Date
                    select qua;
        }

        //filter to date
        if (Request.QueryString["DateTo"] != null && Request.QueryString["DateTo"] != "")
        {
            DateTime dateToFilter;

            dateToFilter = DateTime.Parse(Request.QueryString["DateTo"]);

            Q= from qua in qTable
                    where qua.Start_Date.Date <= dateToFilter.Date
                    && qua.End_Date.Date >= dateToFilter.Date
                    select qua;
        }
```

Comment: Well shouldn't these condition work together ?

Comment: Can you clarify your requirements a bit better? I'm having trouble understanding what date ranges you're actually after. What I've deduced from your requirements above is that you need anything that has any date on it..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want the projects that overlap with any part of your search range, try this:

```
project_start <= search_end AND project_end >= search_start
```

I know it looks "too simple" but it does in fact cover all the cases:

- Partial overlaps at both ends
- The project being completely inside the search range
- The search range being completely inside the project.

**Update**

To handle optional paramaters:

```
(search_end IS NULL OR project_start <= search_end) AND
(search_start IS NULL OR project_end >= search_start)
```

Comment: Both search parameters are optional, so the AND above would not suffice.

Comment: +1 : But also worthy of note: Such a lookup tends to scan very large potions of the table.  Knowing the maximum duration of any interval can speed this up considerably:  `p_start >= s_start - 31 AND p_start <= s_end AND p_end >= s_start`.

Comment: @stats101: Fixed to also handle NULL inputs.

Comment: @stats101 - Then use *place_holders*. If `search_start` is not supplied, replace it with a date earlier than all of your data, such as `'1900 Jan 01 00:00'`, and `search_end` could become `'2070 Jan 01 00:00'`. But the principle of the conditions remains the same.  *(This, in my experience, often gives cleaner execution plans than using the `IS NULL` checks.)*

Comment: @MarkByers In the above, if only search_start was supplied, and it fell before the start date of the project, it would incorrectly be returned as project_end >= project_start.

Comment: @stats101: No it gives "project_end >= **search_start**" which is exactly what you need.

Answer (score 0):

Surely you want:

```
(project_start >= search_start AND project_end >= search_start)
AND
(project_start <= search_end AND project_end <= search_end)
```

Assuming project_end > project_start, this can be simplified to

```
project_start >= search_start AND project_end <= search_end
```

You say both search parameters are optional, in which case make search_start default to DateTime.MinValue, and search_end default to DateTime.MaxValue.